# juju sync-tools on maas 502 bad gateway error

Tags: juju, maas

1) I have maas server on Vm with 4 node all ubuntu 14.04 trusty 
2) I use server ( host of VMs) as JUJU server i tried to bootstrap juju i got this error:

ERROR juju.cmd supercommand.go:300 gomaasapi: got error back from server: 502 Bad Gateway

Answer (score 1):

I tried to find which dns server eturns my proxy ip address:

I watched when I try nslookup 'proxy' on my MAAS server ( VM) the it returned from my forwader dns,

I installed the dnsmasq on MAAS server and my MAAS-DNS returned the ip of proxy and it fixed the problem.